# What are the formulas for the circumradius, surface area and volume of each Kepler-Poinsot polyhderon based on the length of the entire edge?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, derivation-of-formulae

Every formula I've found online is based on only a part of the total edge.  If anyone knows the formulas based on each red edge below I would greatly appreciate it.  A derivation of those formulas would be even better.

[image]

Comment: You should mention the connection with your previous question.

Comment: *"Every formula I've found online is based on only a part of the total edge."* Please provide the formulas you found, and cite the sources for double-checking terminology. This information can give folks a head-start to answering your question without having to derive everything from scratch. Also, please be clear what you mean by "surface area" and "volume" (and even "entire edge") here. Opinions differ about what these terms mean for self-intersecting figures. See, for instance, my discussion of self-intersecting polygon area in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4079922/409).

Comment: https://rechneronline.de/pi/great-icosahedron.php https://rechneronline.de/pi/great-stellated-dodecahedron.php https://rechneronline.de/pi/small-stellated-dodecahedron.php The great dodecahedron one actually has what I want.

Comment: I outlined the "entire edge" I'm referring to in red above...  Surface area is the combined area of all the triangles and volume is the amount of water that would fill one of the shapes if poured in from a small hole in the top...

Comment: @John: Thanks for the info. Please add it to the body of the question itself. (Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.) Also, be considerate of readers by including the formulas directly instead of requiring clicking-through to a third-party site; readers may be (rightfully) wary of following arbitrary links. ... (BTW: If you're addressing a person's comment with your own, be sure to use the @-name feature so that the person receives a notification about it.) ... Cheers!

Comment: The calculator you linked already does exactly what you want. What you call the total edge length is called the pentagram chord in the great stellated dodecahedron.

Comment: ^Thanks.  How hard is it to rewrite the formulas in terms of the chord?  If you're able to do that as an answer I'll give you the bounty.

Comment: A new +500 bounty [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4864802/volume-of-a-great-icosahedron) on a volume of a great icosahedron .

Answer (score 2):

As I understood from the discussion in the comments, a [great stellated dodecahedron](https://rechneronline.de/pi/great-stellated-dodecahedron.php) with the [pentagram chord](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4863226/what-are-the-formulas-for-the-circumradius-surface-area-and-volume-of-each-kepl#comment10374912_4863226)
$c$ has circumsphere radius $$r_c=c\cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}\cdot (3+\sqrt{5})}{4\cdot (2+\sqrt{5})}=
c\cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}\cdot (\sqrt{5}-1)}4,$$
surface area
$$A=c^2\cdot \frac{15\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}}}{(2+\sqrt{5})^2}=c^2\cdot \frac{15\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}}}{9+4\sqrt{5}},$$
and volume $$V =c^3\cdot \frac{5\cdot (3+\sqrt{5})}{4\cdot (2+\sqrt{5})^3}=c^3\cdot \frac{5\cdot (13\sqrt{5}-29)}{4}.$$

To avoid the ambiguity with the multiplication and the division in the formulae at the linked page, I used the provided calculator to numerically check the final formulae above, plugging into them $c=1$.