# Volume of a great icosahedron

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

[image]

This is the image of a Great Icosahedron that I obtained starting from the coordinates of the vertices, as $A$ ,$B$ $C$, etc.. Now I want to calculate the volume of the solid. In internet (as in [this page of Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreatIcosahedron.html)) I can find a formula for this volume,
$$
V=\frac{l^3}{4}(25+9\sqrt{5})
$$

but I can't understand how it is obtained. Some one can explain how it come from.

Comment: you probably ought read that Wolfram page carefully: it states that the given volume formula was derived for an edge incident dodecahedron with unit edges ...

Comment: I have read, but unfortunately I can't understand how to derive the formula. I would need some further explanation.

Comment: You've chosen a slightly difficult image to interpret - having the object oriented with edges in a plane perpendicular to the screen (like the orange edge connected to $E$) and so symmetrically makes features a little hard to see. The 3D animated version on Wikipedia is probably more helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_icosahedron#/media/File:Great_icosahedron.stl Perhaps you can see that this polyhedron can be described as a small stellated dodecahedron with $60$ congruent irregular tetrahedra carved out from it - does that help?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, which I hope will be useful from a didactical point of view. And I'm sorry I can't split the bounty. It is interesting to note that for all other regular polyhedra (convex or not) the volume can be calculated with high school level mathematics knowledge, without the explicit use of a coordinate system, while in this case it seems unavoidable the use of analytic geometry in 3D-space.

Answer (score 5):

Let us rescale the great icosahedron so that its true vertices have as coordinates cyclic permutations of $(\pm1,0,\pm\varphi)$ where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio $\frac{\sqrt5+1}2$, so that its true edge length is $2\varphi$. Then we have the following decomposition:

[image]

[image]

The orange, red and blue vertices in the positive (larger) tetrahedron have coordinates $A=(1,0,\varphi)$, $B=(0,2-\varphi,1)$ and $C=(0,\varphi-2,1)$ respectively; the fourth vertex is the origin. The negative (smaller) tetrahedron shares the first three vertices and its fourth vertex $D$ – black in the above images – lies at the intersection of the two lines between red balls and blue balls in the second image:
$$(1-t)(0,2-\varphi,1)+t(2-\varphi,-1,0)=(1-u)(0,\varphi-2,1)+u(2-\varphi,1,0)\implies t=u=\frac{\varphi-2}{\varphi-3}$$
$$D=\left(\frac{7-4\varphi}5,0,\frac{2+\varphi}5\right)$$
Then the two tetrahedron volumes may be computed as sixths of determinants; they are $\frac{4-2\varphi}6$ for the positive tetrahedron and $\frac{28\varphi-44}{30}$ for the negative one. Thus the volume of a great icosahedron with true edge length $2\varphi$ is
$$60\cdot\frac{4-2\varphi}6-60\cdot\frac{28\varphi-44}{30}=128-76\varphi$$
Finally, using MathWorld's scaling where the tetrahedron red–blue distance is $1$, the volume is
$$\frac{128-76\varphi}{(4-2\varphi)^3}=\frac{9\varphi+8}2=\frac{25+9\sqrt5}4$$

Answer (score 2):

First of all, @ChrisLewis is totally right.
The area of a great icosahedron can be described as the area of a small stellated dodecahedron with $5\cdot 12=60$ congruent irregular tetrahedra carved out from it. For further reference call the side length of the regular dodecahedron $e$.

The area can thus be divided into three subquestions:

1. The [volume of a regular dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_dodecahedron) with edge length $e$ which is $$\frac{e^3}{4}(15+7\sqrt{5}).$$
2. The volume of a pentagonal pyramid with height $e\sqrt{\frac{1}{5} (5+2\sqrt{5})}$, this height is due to [your Wolfram Link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreatIcosahedron.html). This volume is due to this [page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PentagonalPyramid.html) and equals $$\frac{1}{12} e^3\sqrt{25 + 10\sqrt{5}} \sqrt{\frac{1}{5} (5+2\sqrt{5})}$$
3. Now, for the more difficult part we require the volume of 1 of the 60 irregular tetrahedra. A plot of this is at the bottom of this post. We define the regular pentagon $ABCDE$ with coordinates
   $A=\left(0, \sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{10}}e, 0\right)$,
   $B=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}e, \sqrt{\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{40}}e, 0\right)$,
   $C=\left(\frac{e}{2}, -\sqrt{\frac{5+2\sqrt{5}}{20}}e, 0\right)$,
   $D=\left(-\frac{e}{2}, -\sqrt{\frac{5+2\sqrt{5}}{20}}e, 0\right)$,
   $E=\left(-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}e, \sqrt{\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{40}}e, 0\right)$.
   Also define the point $H$ to be the dimple/bottom of the [pentagrammic pyramids](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreatIcosahedron.html) and define point $P$ to be the top of the pentagrammic pyramids, we have
   $H=\left(0, 0, -\sqrt{\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{10}}e\right)$ and
   $P=\left(0, 0, \sqrt{\frac{5+2\sqrt{5}}{5}}e\right)$.
   We draw a line through the points $B$ and $D$ and call the intersection with the y-axis point $F$, we can calculate the coordinates of the point $F$ to be
   $F = \left(0, -\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}(5-2\sqrt{5})}e, 0\right)$, the line through $P$ and $F$ will intersect the equilateral triangle $CHD$ in another point which we call $G$.
   The plane spanned by $CHD$ has equation:
   $$\underbrace{\sqrt{\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{10}}}_{\alpha}y + \underbrace{\sqrt{\frac{5+2\sqrt{5}}{20}}}_{\beta}z + \alpha \beta e = 0$$
   We can parameterize the line through $P$ and $F$ by:
   $$\bigg( 0, 0, \underbrace{\sqrt{\frac{5+2\sqrt{5}}{5}}}_{\eta} e \bigg) + \lambda \bigg( 0, \underbrace{\sqrt{\frac{5-2\sqrt{5}}{5}}}_{\delta}e, \eta e\bigg).$$
   Equating the line and the plane gives the equality $z=-\alpha e - \frac{\alpha}{\beta} \delta e \lambda = \eta (1+\lambda) e$, which implies that $\lambda = -\frac{1}{10}(5+3\sqrt{5})$, substituting this gives $G=\left(0, -\frac{1}{5}\sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2}}e,-\frac{1}{5}\sqrt{\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2}}e \right)$.
   The irregular tetrahedron is formed by points $GCDP$, the volume of such a solid will be one sixth times $e$ times the distance of $G$ to $CD$ times the distance of $P$ to $GCD$. We get a volume of
   \begin{align}
   \frac{1}{6} e^2 &\sqrt{\left(-\frac{1}{5}\sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2}}+\sqrt{\frac{5+2\sqrt{5}}{20}} \right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{5}\sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2}}\right)^2} \cdot \textrm{dist}(P, HCD) \\
   &=\frac{\sqrt{15}}{60}e^2 \cdot \textrm{dist}(P, HCD) \\
   &=\frac{\sqrt{15}}{60}e^2 \frac{\beta \sqrt{\frac{5+2\sqrt{5}}{5}}e + \alpha \beta e}{\sqrt{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}}\\
   &=\frac{\sqrt{15}}{60}e^3 \frac{\frac{1}{10}(5+2\sqrt{5}) + \frac{1}{20}(5+\sqrt{5})}{\sqrt{\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{10} + \frac{5+2\sqrt{5}}{20}}} \\
   &=\frac{\sqrt{15}}{60}e^3 \frac{\frac{1}{4}(3+\sqrt{5})}{\sqrt{3}/2} 
   =\frac{\sqrt{5}}{120}e^3(3+\sqrt{5}) = \frac{5+3\sqrt{5}}{120} e^3
   \end{align}

The total volume of a great icosahedron is thus
\begin{align}
\frac{e^3}{4}(15+7\sqrt{5}) + &12 \cdot \frac{1}{12} e^3\sqrt{25 + 10\sqrt{5}} \sqrt{\frac{1}{5} (5+2\sqrt{5})} - 60 \cdot \frac{5+3\sqrt{5}}{120} e^3\\
=\frac{e^3}{4}(25 + 9 \sqrt{5}).
\end{align}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'll find the point $B$ from the following illustration using the regular icosahedron from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2174594).

[image: dirty illustration]

(sorry to every reader for the godawful "graphic design"...)

Namely, it can be taken as the intersection of planes $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$, where
$$(0,-p,1),(-1,0,-p),(p,1,0) \in P_1,$$
$$(0,-p,1),(1,0,-p),(-p,1,0) \in P_2,$$
$$(0,p,1),(-p,-1,0),(p,-1,0) \in P_3$$
(three equilateral triangles with edge length $2 p = 1 + \sqrt{5}$).

We have a system of linear equations
$$\lambda_1 (-1, p, -p-1) + \mu_1 (p, p+1,-1) =$$
$$=\lambda_2 (1,p,-p-1) + \mu_2 (-p,p+1,-1) =$$
$$=(0,2p, 0) + \lambda_3 (-p,-p-1,-1) + \mu_3 (p, -p-1, -1).$$

CAS computation says $\lambda_3 = \mu_3 = \dfrac{9+4\sqrt{5}}{20+9\sqrt{5}}$ and therefore $B = (0,p,1) - 2\frac{8p+5}{18p+11}(0,p+1,1) = \frac{1}{18p+11}(0,-13p-8,2p+1)$.

Now we just find the tetrahedron volume by the |determinant|/6 formula. The red-blue intersection vertex is at $(p-2, -1, 0)$ (from another $3 \times 2$ system of intersecting lines), the green-blue one is, symmetrically, at $(2-p, -1, 0)$. Again by CAS the volume is $\tilde V_2 = 14/(6 \sqrt{5}) - 1$.

---

[It is not hard to see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagram#Golden_ratio) that the dodecahedron in our problem has edge length $2/p^2$, so we'll rescale and use $V_2 = \tilde V_2 \frac{8}{p^6}$ in the final calculation.

The regular [dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_dodecahedron#Surface_area_and_volume) with edge $1$ has volume $V_0 = (15+7\sqrt{5})/4$.

The upper part of the "pentagrammatic pyramid" [has height](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreatIcosahedron.html) $\sqrt{1 + 2/\sqrt{5}}$, so the volume $V_1$ of its convex hull is that [times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon#Regular_pentagons) $\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{25 + 10 \sqrt{5}}/4$, or in other words, $V_1 = \frac{5 + 2 \sqrt{5}}{12}$.

Now we need only calculate $V_0 + 12 (V_1 - 5 V_2)$. This is a pleasant exercise for the reader...